# How to determine if a pass-by-reference variable is set?

Tags: php

For an arbitrary function declared as follows:

```
function foo($first, &$second = null) {
    // if ($second is assigned) {
    //     Work with $second
    // }
}
```

How does one determine if `$second` is indeed assigned to a variable at call time, eg.:

```
foo('hello', $second);
```

vs

```
foo('hello'); // Notice &$second is unassigned
```

Tried `isset()`, `is_null()` but they don't seem to work.

#### Update:

Created a [test script here](http://codepad.org/HHaVoXrc) here

Comment: func_num_args()

Comment: Thanks Jack. Didn't think of that one. That would work. :)
Any idea for a more specific one that deals directly with `$second`?

Comment: Personally I would simply use: if ($second) {}

Comment: Please post your _actual_ testcase, since both `isset` and `is_null` "work" just fine for me.

Comment: Just added a testcase here: http://codepad.org/HHaVoXrc Thanks for all the great discussions on this.

Comment: @uzyn: This adds new factors, as I indicated on the comment in my answer. A _real_ testcase (yours with an added line) is here: http://codepad.org/uJUvzW7n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's my understanding that you wish to implement a function that implements something like `preg_match`, whereby the third argument gets populated with the memory patterns if passed.

Internally, PHP functions use a function called `zend_parse_parameters()`; it accepts a format string and a variable number of arguments that will be populated with the meta data of the call parameters. If a parameter is not passed (e.g. when it's optional), the meta data is not available and thus is easy to detect.

Coming back to PHP itself, unfortunately there's no such thing as `func_arg_used($var)` that will tell you if `$var` was passed as a function argument; perhaps this would be an interesting contribution to the language, but until then you'll have to settle for something more ancient :)

```
if (func_num_args() > 1) {
    // $second was passed and can be used to populate
}
```

You may have to be careful when changing the signature of the function, especially when you add parameters in front of `$second`; however, naturally this shouldn't happen often because it would most definitely break dependent functions. Adding more arguments at the end has no effect on above code.

There are two ways you can go with this:

1. [`ReflectionFunction`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) - the shiny new toy of developers, it allows you to introspect your function and determine whether the signature changed from when it was created. Use it sparingly though, introspection is not cheap, especially considering the alternativey.
2. The humble code comment - the much understated form of code policing; a simple line that says `// IMPORTANT - don't add arguments before $second`

Comment: Thanks for the very well explained answer, Jack. Indeed I was looking to implement something like `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (as far as I know) tell the difference between NULL and Undefined using isset. You could set default value of $second to some random value that will never be used otherwise.

```
define('UNDEFINED', -19181818);

function foo($first, &$second = UNDEFINED) 
{
 if($second==UNDEFINED)
 {
  etc..
 }
}
```

Comment: `null` is already a "value" (not really) that will never be used. If you're using it as a "value" other than "this variable is not defined", then you're doing PHP wrong. :)

Comment: The problem is null and undefined are treated the same when testing if a variable has been set however there is a subtle difference in the two. In this case you need to test against a variable which does not equate to null, unless there is some other low level function in php I'm not aware of. Or of couse use func_num_args which is probably a cleaner way to do this (unless there will be a 3rd and 4th arg etc!.

Comment: Because PHP treats them the same, so should we. I don't understand why everyone wants to make a distinction for sending a variable set to `null` into the function. What's the subtle difference? Barring breaking the abstraction defined by the language and looking at implementation details, that is.

Comment: NULL is a value which can be used to identify if a variable contains no data. It can be passed to, and returned by functions. Also, PHP will throw an error if you try to access an undefined variable. I'm sure there are a few other areas where PHP does not treat them the same. I agree, I don't understand why the OP wants to do what he is doing, but I can see a few other valid scenarios where you might want to tell the difference between undefined and null.

Comment: I can't see that the OP has asked to make any such distinction, but since you're the second person to claim otherwise perhaps I should conclude blindness on my part.

Answer (score 1):

[Works for me](http://codepad.org/EP9sToyO):

```
<?php

function bool_str($b)
{
    return ($b ? "true" : "false");
}

function foo($first, &$second = null)
{
    echo bool_str(isset($first)) . " " . bool_str(isset($second)) . " " .
         bool_str(is_null($first)) . " " . bool_str(is_null($second)) . "\n";
}

$a = 1;
$b = 2;

foo($a, $b);
foo($a);

?>
```

Output:

```
true true false false
true false false true
     ^^^^^       ^^^^
```

Which is precisely what I would expect, i.e. you can use both `isset` and `is_null` here.

Comment: this fails for the case `$b = null;`

Comment: @rambocoder: That's because there is no distinction between a variable set to `null` and a variable that doesn't exist. They are one and the same. That's why setting something to `null` is a way of freeing it up. Trying to force a distinction between the two is a fool's errand as it goes against the grain of PHP's design. Also the OP didn't ask for it.

Comment: There is a distinction. A non existent variable will not appear in the symbol table. For example, via [get_defined_vars](http://www.php.net/get_defined_vars)(). Regardless, your solution doesn't robustly answer the specific question that was asked(although it's probably a sufficient and good solution for most).

Comment: @rambocoder: The symbol table is not relevant. Programming in PHP involves treating variables set to `null` as indistinct from variables that have not been declared. Thus my solution is 100% robust according to the contracts of the language. Delving through the language's abstractions into implementation specifics is getting into a whole other story.

Comment: Bottom line: your answer fails for the test case he gave. I provided an example. End.

Comment: @rambocoder: Huh? Look again. He didn't give a test case where `null` were expected to be a valid value, not at all. You're the only one who's been claiming that this needs to be accepted! In fact my example _exactly_ matches the scenario in the question.

Comment: *"How does one determine if $second is indeed assigned to a variable at call time"*. He never specified "non null valued", and so it must wpork for all cases where it was a variable. Seriously, get over it. I know you want to be right and all but...

Comment: @rambocoder: Well, I _am_ right. As I said before, the PHP language makes no distinction between variables set to `null` and variables that have not even been declared. There is no "where [null] was a variable". But this is the last comment I shall make on the subject, so let's agree to disagree.

Comment: Don't think `is_null()` works. Created a test script here: http://codepad.org/HHaVoXrc

Comment: @uzyn: I already demonstrated that it works with a testcase that doesn't introduce other factors. You've introduced the factor of using a pass-by-reference variable later, and the reason it doesn't work is that you didn't declare it before use: http://codepad.org/uJUvzW7n

Answer (score 1):

I think the suggestion by Jack to use [func_num_args](http://www.php.net/func_num_args)() is excellent.

```
function foo($first, &$second = null) {
    if (func_num_args() > 1) {
        //$second MUST be assigned
    }
}
```

This properly detects when `$second` references a variable which exists in the calling scopes' symbol table, yet it has a variable value of null.

```
$second = null;
foo('hello', $second);
```

Comment: I can confirm that `func_num_args()` works. (Thanks Jack!) Didn't think of that when I first asked this question, but now I'm wondering if there's one that deals specifically with the pass-by-reference variable in case the function signature changes _(and the programmer forgets to update `func_num_args()`)_.